# Google Earth Engine - slope

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, elevation, slope, terrain

I am trying to use the pre-built function of GEE for calculating the slope of the terrain, but I cannot really understand how the function works, since [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-terrain-slope) is also not really helpful.

Can anyone provide an explanation about its mechanism? For example, which kind of formula it uses to extract the slope from a DEM.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a DEM stored in GEE like the SRTM DEM.

```
var dem = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(dem);
```

Comment: While this shows how to implement the function,  the question is asking how the function works. I.e. the algorithm or formula it uses to arrive at its output. The only information in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-terrain-slope) is that *"The local gradient is computed using the 4-connected neighbors of each pixel"*, which is vague and, as the question says, not very helpful.